# Syntax error when trying to store an array into sql table

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Im trying to store an array like

```
[0102,0103,0103]
```

into a sql table.
Im using this query:

```
INSERT INTO public."OrderDetail" ("PaidsProducts")
VALUES ('{0102,0102,0103}') 
WHERE "ID_Order" = '010'
```

but im getting this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 3: WHERE "ID_Order" = '010'
        ^
SQL state: 42601
 Character: 81
```

Any idea?
Thanks all

Comment: you need an `update` statement not `insert` statement.

Comment: It looks like you want to do an `update`.  This is for an existing row with `ID_Order = '010'`, right?

Comment: @zealous thanks! It works!

Comment: @MikeOrganek thanks! It works!